# How to use .Union to use 2 "Type" parameters in .SpecialCells Method

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy some data from a Range but i can't make it work the way i need.

I need `xlCellTypeConstants` to skip blanks in the range.
I need `xlCellTypeFormulas` to also copy the cells with formulas in the range

But when i run the macro i get this error: "Object doesn't support this property or method", in this code line:

```
Set SumRange = .Range("B5:B29").Union(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants), .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas))
```

I need to do this like this because i'm copying the data and pasting it with transpose because i need it in the same row.

Any ideas would be extremely appreciated.

```
  Sub WorksheetLoopSummary()
     Dim WS_Count As Integer
     Dim i As Integer
     Dim LastRow As Long
     Dim SumRange As Range

     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

     For i = 5 To WS_Count
        With Worksheets(i)
            Set SumRange = .Range("B5:B29").Union(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants), .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas))
            SumRange.Copy
            LastRow = Sheets("Summary").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).row
            Worksheets("Summary").Range("A" & LastRow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
        End With
     Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Union is a method of Application object.

You could do the following (change Activesheet as required)

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("B5:B29")
    Set SumRange = Union(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants), .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas))
End With
```

As @chrisneilsen mentions: If these conditions are not met you will have an error thrown which you need to handle. Common checks include checking that range is not empty before attempting to use SpecialCells and testing if formulas are present.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning OP should account for possibility SpecialCells throws an error

Comment: @chrisneilsen Well spotted indeed.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. Does this not answer the question?

Comment: Hi QHarr, your answer was very helpful to me and i really thank you, i don't know why is your answer voted as a bad answer.